# Updating an index with logstash fails, likely bug?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am practicing with Logstash and I can't understand the source of this error.
I want to modify an index by removing a field and renaming one.
I'm on Logstash 5.6.2

This is an example of my entries:

```
{
    "_index": "test-shakespeare-italian",
    "_type": "logs",
    "_id": "AV8QsD5pzoUbREG_8icr",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "nome_opera": "Henry IV",
      "battuta_numero": "3.2.9",
      "battuta": "Make me believe that thou art only markd",
      "@timestamp": "2017-10-12T13:05:06.519Z",
      "id_battuta": 1841,
      "dialogo_numero": 1,
      "@version": "1",
      "interlocutore": "KING HENRY IV"
    }
  }
```

This is my pipeline:

```
# this pipeline updates an existing index by
# changing name of field "nome_opera" in "opera"
# dropping field "dialogo numero"
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost"
    index => "test-shakespeare-italian"
    query => '{"query": {"match_all": {}}}'
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    rename => { "nome_opera" => "opera"}
    remove_field => "dialogo_numero"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { 
    index => "test-shakespeare-italian"
    action => "update"
    document_id => "OOW-j2DeSCmnsVWVsywOVQ"
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    version => "1"
  }
  #stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

First I was not using the version field, but this produced the following error:

```
[2017-10-13T11:29:25,464][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Failed action. {:status=>409, :action=>["update", {:_id=>"OOW-j2DeSCmnsVWVsywOVQ", :_index=>"test-shakespeare-italian", :_type=>"logs", :_routing=>nil, :_retry_on_conflict=>1}, 2017-10-12T13:05:08.907Z %{host} %{message}], :response=>{"update"=>{"_index"=>"test-shakespeare-italian", "_type"=>"logs", "_id"=>"OOW-j2DeSCmnsVWVsywOVQ", "status"=>409, "error"=>{"type"=>"version_conflict_engine_exception", "reason"=>"[logs][OOW-j2DeSCmnsVWVsywOVQ]: version conflict, current version [17901] is different than the one provided [17900]", "index_uuid"=>"OOW-j2DeSCmnsVWVsywOVQ", "shard"=>"3", "index"=>"test-shakespeare-italian"}}}}
```

Then I added the version field but still the pipeline fails with the following error:

```
[2017-10-13T11:38:39,467][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Encountered an unexpected error submitting a bulk request! Will retry. {:error_message=>"undefined method `sanitized' for \"http://localhost:9200/_bulk\":String", :class=>"NoMethodError", :backtrace=>["/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.6.2/libexec/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.4.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:249:in `safe_bulk'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.6.2/libexec/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.4.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:119:in `submit'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.6.2/libexec/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.4.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:87:in `retrying_submit'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.6.2/libexec/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.4.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:38:in `multi_receive'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.6.2/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator_strategies/shared.rb:13:in `multi_receive'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.6.2/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:49:in `multi_receive'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.6.2/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:436:in `output_batch'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.6.2/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:435:in `output_batch'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.6.2/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:381:in `worker_loop'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.6.2/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:342:in `start_workers'"]}
```

- I am sure that the document_id is correct.
- The pipeline works perfectly if instead of updating the index I create a new one
- --config.test_and_exit gives OK

Online I found this
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-encountered-an-unexpected-error-submitting-a-bulk-request-undefined-method-sanitized/103360/2

and this
https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/issues/612

Which leads me to think this is a bug, not my fault.
Unfortunately no real solution is provided in those links, do I have to revert to an older version of logstash? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you take the final result via stdout and apply it via bulk api?

I am thinking it must be a problem with your final JSON after filter processor

Comment: How can I update the same index with bulk apis?
BTW, I tried to look for other ways and I accomplished this in SECONDS with bulk APIs and the script field.
If updating an index with logstash is so complicated, I guess I would go with just creating a new one everytime. I don't plan to modify my data that often.
Is it a good idea though?